# How to set text on textview from an ArrayList of unknown size

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am receiving a response from the server in an `ArrayList` of `String`. Now how can I set those strings on `TextView`? The size of the `ArrayList` is unknown.

Comment: you can use ListView to show all the text in the textview, So that people can scroll and read.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I am using recyclerview. The question is for receiving data for a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

When you do get the response from the server then you know the size of the ArrayList so try this method I think it should do the trick!

```
public void setTextViewValues (ArrayList<String> vals, TextView text) {
    //Variable to hold all the values
    String output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++) {
        //Append all the values to a string
        output += vals.get(i);
    }

    //Set the textview to the output string
    text.setText(output);
}
```

Comment: You are right. I thought about running a for loop, but forgot about appending strings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add all values to one string value

```
String result = "";
for (String s : arrayList) {
  result +=s;
}
```

And then set it

```
textView.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you mean?
Display it in a row?

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : arrayListName){
     builder.append(s+" ,");
}
textView.setText(builder.toString());
```

Comment: Right. I thought about running a for loop, but forgot about appending strings.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply convert your arry of string into a string with the method

```
Arrays.toString(YourArray);
```

wich will convert your arry into a string
then you simply put it in the textView.setText like this

```
textView.setText(Arrays.toString(YourArray));
```

And if you want it displayed without the special character you can just add this

```
textView.setText(Arrays.toString(YourArray).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
```